# Xcode 9.0 structure highlighting(⌘+hover) not working only for switch cases

Tags: swift, xcode

This question is not directly pointed to code errors but anyways. I am getting used with new Xcode 9.0 beta and I discovered very good new feature, which is structure highlighting(⌘+hover) on ending brackets  ( **}** ) then you can see the starting bracket. However, it seems that it doesn't work for `switch cases`.

My question is, is it supposed to be like this or is this a bug?[image]

Comment: It's probably a bug, after all it is just a beta.

Comment: @EliWhittle That is what I thought. I just wanted to be sure before I send bug report.